# How to make Basic jQuery Slider to stop after 1 loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, jquery-plugins, slideshow

I'm using this basic jQuery slider, but like it to stop after 1 cycle and not loop. I don't see that as one of the options for customization. Any idea how to customize on top of it?

http://www.basic-slider.com/

Thanks in advance!

This is what I have so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

          $('#banner-slide').bjqs({

            // w + h to enforce consistency
            width           : 660,
            height          : 235,

            // transition valuess
            animtype        : 'slide',
            animduration    : 350,      // length of transition
            animspeed       : 10000,     // delay between transitions
            automatic       : true,     // enable/disable automatic slide rotation

            // control and marker configuration
            showcontrols    : false,     // enable/disable next + previous UI elements
            centercontrols  : false,     // vertically center controls
            nexttext        : 'Next',   // text/html inside next UI element
            prevtext        : 'Prev',   // text/html inside previous UI element
            showmarkers     : false,     // enable/disable individual slide UI markers
            centermarkers   : false,     // horizontally center markers

            // interaction values
            keyboardnav     : false,     // enable/disable keyboard navigation
            hoverpause      : false,     // enable/disable pause slides on hover

            // presentational options
            usecaptions     : false,     // enable/disable captions using img title attribute
            randomstart     : false,     // start from a random slide
            responsive      : false,     // enable responsive behaviour

          });


        });
```

Comment: 1st try yourself,and than post some code - so that we can help you

Comment: I've noticed other jquery sliders plugin have the loop option, but not in this basic slider. I've already incorporated this slider in my page so I can't switch to a different plugin now, but wondering if there is something I can add to make it stop after 1 cycle. Each slide is a list item, so I just need it to stop at the last list item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have customized and added an option to stop this automatic slider after a loop. Slide change will stop at the last slide. option called 'rotate'. By default, its true. You need to set it as false to avoid next rotation.

Code will be like

```
$('#banner-fade').bjqs({
        height      : 320,
        width       : 620,
        responsive  : true,
        automatic   : true,
        rotate  : false,
 });
```

You can find the updated plugin jquery file on the following links

1. Basic slider [Normal](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p4egkqfj79v87bn/bjqs-1.3.js) 
   [Minified](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ll1ja4z7yrg4kg/bjqs-1.3.min.js)

Comment: I added rotate  : false, and it's still rotating. I tried both the minified and development version. I will clear my browser cache and try again.

Comment: Yep. Still rotating. I will upload the files, maybe you can see what I'm missing. Thanks.

Comment: Have download those files from that link and changed it in your code? Please upload the files and Give me the link.

Comment: So, here is the (not working) example: http://heidixu.com/misc/slider/test.html with the new updated js:http://heidixu.com/misc/slider/js/bjqs-1.3.js

Comment: Hey, I forgot to write code for rotate stop when the animtype set as slide. Now Its working. Please download the updated file. [Normal](https://db.tt/aeyJtnmR) [minified](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/95577986/bjqs-1.3.min.js)